# Не передаются данные в почтовый клиент Gmail

Tags: java, android, email

В приложении пользователь вводит тему и текст сообщения и потом с помощью почтового клиента отправляет.
Не передаются данные в почтовый клиент Gmail. Отправка через Яндекс работает.

Собственно так реализованно в приложении:

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!validateForm()) {
                    return;
                }
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                i.setType("text/plain");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , message.getText().toString());
                i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"));
                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Отправить сообщение..."));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(SendEmail.this, "Отсутствуют установленные почтовые клиенты", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно официальной [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#ComposeEmail) (я проверил у меня работает):

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        String[] addresses = {"test@gmail.com"};
        i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "MySubject");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "MyMessage");

        if( i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Отправить сообщение..."));
        }else{
            Toast.makeText( Main.this, "Отсутствуют установленные почтовые клиенты",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```